# How to inflate a xml layout in order to implement a listener for an android seekbar?

Tags: java, xml, android-seekbar

I have been spending hours trying to implement a seekbar listener for my android app. Everytime I start the application it crashes.
I am trying to link the seekbar to a Threshold that can be manually changed over the seekbar. This is my layout xml file for the seekbar:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="126dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minWidth="56dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="188dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.SeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/progressBar"
        android:max="127"
        android:progress="2" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seekBar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My implementation looks as follows:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress, null );
    setContentView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
    final int step = 1;
    final int max = 0;
    final int min = -127;
    Threshold = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    //Threshold.setMax( (max - min) / step );
    Threshold.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progressChangedValue;
        //@Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar Threshold, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser)
        {
            // if progress = 13 -> value = 3 + (13 * 0.1) = 4.3
            double value = min + (progress * step);
            progressChangedValue = (int) value;
            //progressChangedValue = progress;
        }
        //@Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar Threshold) {}

        //@Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar Threshold) {
            mThreshold = progressChangedValue;
            Toast.makeText(DeviceScanActivity.this, "Threshold has been set to: " + progressChangedValue,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}
```

Does anyone have a hint what may cause the crash of the app? And how I could solve the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Sayus

Answer (score 0):

You don't require to inflate a layout by yourself as `setContentView()` method does the same for you.

So remove `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress, null );` from your code and it will stop crashing.

Comment: @ Jack ray: thanks a lot for your answer. But my application still crashes after I removed:     getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress, null );

Comment: can you post the error trace here so that i can get more closer view to your problem?